# How to put one picture partially overlapping another in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

In Word, I can do things like this

[image]

I cannot find a corresponding option in Google Docs. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible in google docs.. have a look at this: http://www.techadvisory.org/2014/04/editing-pictures-in-google-docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the picture you can choose text wrapping options from it's bottom contextmenu. Here is an [example doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1w7quR_WC2YcAEFj0TC40wGLDDHVCFQFOqxivfXDhZOg/copy?usp=sharing) you can copy from.

*In this example, I used another hidden setting for floating pictures in Google Docs. Call it free- floating. The context menu in GDocs then shows no attributes at all. The setting is only accessible when you convert from an existing office document. That workaround involves you use Libre Writer (https://www.rollapp.com/app/lowriter) to position pictures, choose the float and anchor settings, save, convert to GDocs. The nice part is that these attributes survive replacement (contextmenu, replace image). So next time around you can copy the free-floating picture from this exampledoc to your new Gdoc, change it's contents and still maintain float.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

So if you go to Insert, then drawing, it will pull up the window like in the picture, you can import pictures and arrange them how you want. Then click save and close and it will insert the new picture.

Answer (score 3):

You can force image stacking behavior by selecting "wrap text" with a margin of 0.

Comment: I don't see it. Where is that in the UI?

Answer (score 2):

You can set both images to float above the text with [this add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-above-text-for-goog/decefabomgkfanilapdlifchjeofkacg), and then overlap the images:

[image]

Comment: ... it seems you have forgotten to finish your answer. Please [edit] it.

Comment: sorry for that, fixed now!

Comment: @Herrgott that wasn't my downvote...

Comment: The link is dead